# How can i retrieve data from a List in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list saved on firebase that contains coordinates (LatLng). I am trying to retrieve them with this code and use them to add a polyline:

```
ThePath1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
ThePath2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
ThePath = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
databasePaths = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Paths").child("Ola");
databasePaths.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot items: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {


            double infos = items.child("latitude").getValue(double.class);
            double info = items.child("longitude").getValue(double.class);
            ThePath1.add(infos);
            ThePath2.add(info);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ThePath1.size(); i++){
            latt = ThePath1.get(i);
            longg = ThePath2.get(i);
            latLng1 = new LatLng(latt, longg);
            ThePath.add(latLng1);
        }
   }

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
 options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
for  (int i = 0; i  <  ThePath.size(); i++)  {
        LatLng  point  = (LatLng) ThePath.get(i);
        options.add(point);
    }
    line = mMap.addPolyline(options);
```

The problem is that the ArrayList "ThePath" seems to be empty because no polyline appears on the map. How can i get the latitude and longitude from firebase? I post Paths.class and Ola.class here. Please help me with this one, i am stuck.

And here i post Paths.class:

```
import java.util.List;


public class Paths {
String id;
String name;
String city;
String nomos;
String perifereia;
List<Ola> ola;


public Paths(){

}



public Paths(String id, String name, String city, String nomos, String perifereia, List<Ola> ola) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    this.nomos = nomos;
    this.perifereia = perifereia;
    this.ola = ola;

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getNomos() {
    return nomos;
}

public String getPerifereia() {
    return perifereia;
}

public List<Ola> getOla() {
    return ola;
}


}
```

And Ola.class:

```
public class Ola {

public double latitude;
public double longitude;


public Ola() {}

public Ola(double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
}
```

Comment: Plz Post Paths.java class

Comment: Ok i posted it.

Comment: Use info.getOla(). Where info is a reference variable of Paths class

Comment: Now it is a List. How can i add its coordinates to polyline?